# Fluid Layout GWT

Tags: gwt, layout, uibinder

I'm developing a webapp which shall be used on an ipad. Therefor I have to create a dynamic ui. Cause when I rotate the ipad, the side shall be arranged new. I'm working with uibinder(widgets) to create my layout. Is there a widget, which allows the layout to arrangeitself new, when the ipad rotates?
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achive is called responsive design. You can implement a respsonive design yourself or use one of css frameworks listed below:

- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)
- [HTML 5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/tree/v4.2.0)

There are already two implementations for bootstrap with gwt so you could use one of them as your starting point.

- http://nyao.github.io/bootstrap4gwt/
- http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/